# PhpMyAdmin Export size

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have export the sql file for one my client but something is make me confuse.

I view the total size for the SQL in phpmyadmin and it is show this

[image: total size]

But, when I Export it, it just become 7.07mb only. Does is something wrong or no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is totally fine, there is nothing wrong.

When we export database, SQL compress it, so that's why the size of exported database is less than the actual size.

so no worries :)

Comment: Nope, SQL does not compress. In fact it is a lot more verbose, because you need all the `INSERT INTO ...` stuff

Answer (score 1):

Those two sizes are only losely connected. Here are two reasons:

- When you insert into a table and then delete the record, the space might still be allocated to the table. But on export, the row will take 0 bytes.
- A table is made up from data and index. On export, you will only get the data; the space allocated for the export is not needed in your SQL.

As a quick check, you can count the number of lines in your SQL export. Depending on the export configuration, that is as easy as counting `INSERT INTO` statements.